# spring-cloud-aws unable to instantiate cache-manager in a web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-elasticache

I'm running my application in CloudFoundry (PWS) and trying to leverage Spring Cloud AWS Elasticache support to cache data. My configuration is shown below -

```
<aws-context:context-region region="us-east-1"/>
   <aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${my.accessKey}" secret-key="${my.secretKey}"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<aws-cache:cache-manager id="cacheManager">
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="A" expiration="864000"/>
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="B" expiration="2592000"/>
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="C" expiration="2592000"/>
</aws-cache:cache-manager>
```

And in my DAO, I have -

@Cacheable(value="A", key="#p0")
    public Board findById(Long id) throws DataAccessException {}

But I can't seem to get past the IdleConnectionReaper sleep interrupted issue. Please see error details below -

```
2015-05-29T02:32:35.17-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2015-05-29 06:32:35,174 - DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.amazonaws.request - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
```

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2015-05-29 06:32:35,178 - DEBUG java-sdk-http-connection-reaper com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper - Reaper thread:

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:112)

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2015-05-29 06:32:35,183 - DEBUG java-sdk-http-connection-reaper com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper - Shutting down reaper thread.

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3068a787' of type [org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.ElastiCacheFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'caches' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3068a787': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2015-05-29 06:32:35,183 - ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)

......

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.ElastiCacheFactoryBean.createInstance(ElastiCacheFactoryBean.java:74)

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.ElastiCacheFactoryBean.createInstance(ElastiCacheFactoryBean.java:36)

2015-05-29T02:32:35.18-0400 [App/0]   OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)

Comment: Were you able to fix it?